# How to take values from file while posting form data using python or pycurl

Tags: python, pycurl

One of my text contains say smaple.txt 
1234
4567
7894
These values should be passed into form data in pycurl.
I have tried in this way but it gives me an error:

```
import pycurl
import os
try:
    # python 3
     from urllib.parse import urlencode
except ImportError:
    # python 2
    from urllib import urlencode

class FileReader:
    def __init__(self, fp):
         self.fp = fp
    def read_callback(self, size):
       return self.fp.read(size)
c = pycurl.Curl()
filesize = os.path.getsize('smaple.txt')
with open('smaple.txt', 'r') as f:
    c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDSIZE, filesize)
    c.setopt(pycurl.READFUNCTION, FileReader(f).read_callback)
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://app.spongecell.com/api/queries')
        c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['content-type: multipart/form-data'])
        post_data = {'user_credentials': 'xxxxxxx','query':'{campaign(id:line){name,status }}'}
# Form data must be provided already urlencoded.
            postfields = urlencode(post_data)
# Sets request method to POST,
# Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
# and data to send in request body.
            c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)
            c.perform()
            c.close()
```

> ERROR:{"errors":[{"message":"Argument 'id' on Field 'campaign' has an invalid value. Expected type 'ID!'.","locations":[{"line":1,"column":2}],"fields":["query","campaign","id"]}]}

Could anyone please help. As I am new to python.

Comment: It looks like this is going to be an error in your post_body, you might need to look at the documentation for that vendors API